# How to set time calculation in MediaRecorder

Tags: android

I am doing application with MediaRecorder, i want to display the time limit of recording the audio. MediaRecorder is only used to record the voice. anyone know how to display the time while doing MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the ground work laid for the recording and stopping of audio with MediaRecorder written, obtaining duration of recording isn't too difficult.

Displaying duration is simply `start_time` being set to `System.currentTimeMillis();` at start of record.

Then by using a `Runnable` we can perform a loop until stop of record.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable update_runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateTextView();
    }
};
```

Then with the `updateTextView()` you'd do something like this:

```
long duration = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time) / 1000);
// ... set TextView with duration value
handler.postDelayed(update_runnable, 1000); // handler re-executes the Runnable
                                            // every second; which calls
                                            // updateTextView
```